# How to Insert function w/ dynamic value into every cell in column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to paste and execute a function in every cell of column "F" over an unknown number rows.

The function is `=QM_Stream_Delta(Value)`

where `Value` is the cell contents of column "A" of the corresponding row.

[image]

Here's is my VBA script so far:

```
Sub GetDelta()
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Integer
    myFormula = "=QM_Stream_Delta(Value)"
    For i = 9 To FinalRow
        OptionSymbol = Cells(i, "A")
        Cells(i, "F").Value(myFormula(OptionSymbol)
    Next i
End Sub
```

I'm not sure how to actually get the function in there though -- I'm getting a syntax error for

`Cells(i, "F").Value(myFormula(OptionSymbol)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a reference to a cell within your formula.

```
Sub GetDelta()
    Const StartRow As Long = 9

    Dim FinalRow As Long
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("F" & StartRow & ":F" & FinalRow).Formula = "=QM_Stream_Delta(A" & StartRow & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: This would insert `=QM_Stream_Delta(A1)`. The OP wrote `cell contents`, and anyway, why would complicate it that much, if you can just fill it downward?

Comment: OP's screenshot has `A1`, not `A`. Also there's no need for a loop here or "filling downward."

Comment: Maybe because he has not succeeded, yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another use case for `Formula2R1C1`.

```
Sub GetDelta()
    Dim Target As Range
    
    Set Target = Range("F1").Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set Target = Intersect(Target, Target.Offset(8))
    
    Target.Formula2R1C1 = "=@QM_Stream_Delta(RC1)"
End Sub
```

We should be in the habit of fully qualifying our references.  Here I qualified the Target range to the Delta worksheet.

```
Sub GetDelta()
    Dim Target As Range
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Delta")
        Set Target = .Range("F1").Resize(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        Set Target = Intersect(Target, Target.Offset(8))
    End With
    Target.Formula2R1C1 = "=@QM_Stream_Delta(RC1)"
End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen All done!  Thanks I'm a bit rusty to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

One issue i noticed is that you're starting your loop at row `9` rather than row `1`. Your screenshot shows you **want** the inserted formulas to start at row `1`.

I changed your macro to build the *"function"* you want, and then put it in the cell.

The function:

```
Sub GetDelta()
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myFormula As String
    For i = 1 To FinalRow
        myFormula = "=QM_Stream_Delta(A" & i & ")"
        Cells(i, "F").Formula = myFormula
    Next i
End Sub
```

I run it and it populates column `F` with the function. I don't know what the function `QM_Stream_Delta()` is, but the VBA macro places the formula in the cells:

[image]

So now you can run the VBA function, and automatically add the call to `QM_Stream_Delta()` in the rows you want, in the column you want:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  |  |  |  | `=QM_Stream_Delta(A1)` |
| B |  |  |  |  | `=QM_Stream_Delta(A2)` |
| C |  |  |  |  | `=QM_Stream_Delta(A3)` |

Personally, I don't quite understand the virtue of this; Excel already has the ability to quickly populate a column of values. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)